# twython - unsecured server vs secured server

Tags: python, twython

I have a set of Python/Twython code to get one's followers, friends of followers etc. It works fine on unsecured server but getting friends of followers failed when running on secured sever. The Proxy should be ok because I can get followers without problem.
Update: withdrew the question.

Comment: Show your code and any error messages you're getting.

Comment: First time post question here, not familiar with the format. Here is part of the error message:

Comment: @Shaun: error message added. Thanks.